# Difference between Mobius transformation and invertible function $f:\mathbb{C_{\infty}}\mapsto \mathbb{C_{\infty}}$

Tags: functions, inverse, mobius-transformation, mobius-function

I was under the impression that the Mobius maps were exactly all of the bijections $f:\mathbb{C_{\infty}} \mapsto \mathbb{C_{\infty}}$, however I came across the following question

> Show that an invertible function $f:\mathbb{C_{\infty}}\mapsto \mathbb{C_{\infty}}$ that preserves the cross ratio is a Mobius transformation.

which clearly seems to imply that this is not the case! Clearly all maps of the form $z \mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}, ad-bc\neq 0$ are bijections. But I cannot think of a bijection $\mathbb{C_{\infty}}\mapsto \mathbb{C_{\infty}}$ that is not of this form and thus would not be a Mobius map! Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The only _holomorphic_ bijections are Mobius transformations. There are certainly other bijections, for example $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=0$ and $f(z)=z$ for $z\ne 0,1$.

Comment: or $z \mapsto \bar z$